# Scaning through all element without using index

Tags: scala, orientdb, gremlin

I am using gremlin scala and orientdb. I want to search all vertexes with label. I have more than certain amount of vertices it starts to take a while to get some results(10 or more seconds).

- Count of class with label A is 6
- Count of class with label B is 10 000

My problem is that operations on A is slow as on B and I don´t know why.

- g.V.hasLabel("A").toList()
- g.V.has("class","A").toList()
- g.V.hasLabel("B").toList()
- g.V.has("class","B").toList()

In [this thread](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/issues/79) is written about that. It is slow because it is like full table scan. But it looks like it take all vertices in g.V step and start sorting after that.

Answer (score 2):

Most graph databases do not optimize traversals that rely solely on vertex label. That is likely the case here as you are getting the full list of vertices which are then being filtered on label in memory. If OrientDB has the ability to quickly retrieve counts by label, then orientdb-gremlin should be modified to support that and expose that feature.

Apache TinkerPop allows graph databases to expose their strengths and unique characteristics through `TraversalStrategy` implementations. A strategy takes the traversal prior to execution and allows the graph database to optimize it given its features.

For example, consider TinkerGraph - it has the ability to get global counts really quickly because it's backed by an in-memory `Map`. So we developed [TinkerGraphCountStrategy](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/c0571dfd2e87c8830b5c4bd27eea3dadbadba9b0/tinkergraph-gremlin/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/tinkergraph/process/traversal/strategy/optimization/TinkerGraphCountStrategy.java) which replaces the standard `count()` step with a TinkerGraph optimized one which can access that `Map` directly. When variations of `g.V().count()` (or `g.E().count()`) is executed against TinkerGraph, there is no longer a full table scan - you just get an immediate count.

Comment: Problem is that is filtering without label.. He wants all vertexes with the same label in memory, but its look like its get all vertexes to memory and than filtering by label..

Comment: I think that's in line with what I wrote. It doesn't surprise me that it is working that way. As I said, I'm not aware of many graphs that behave differently when requesting graph elements by label - all vertices are returned and then filtered in the has step. If a specific graph can optimize that, then they need to develop a `TraversalStrategy` to expose that performance enhancement to ONLY return the vertices with that label. In other words, there is no way to fix this with TinkerPop/Gremlin. It is a problem for the underlying graph database which in this case is OrientDB.

Comment: But The same request in graph studio(directly to OrientDB) is fast ... But only gremlin is slow up to 10 seconds. That is not problem of OrientDB.

Comment: I'm sorry - perhaps i'm not being clear. If OrientDB itself is fast with a query that gets "vertices by label" then orientdb-gremlin needs to be modified to enable that same speed in a Gremlin query. orientdb-gremlin needs to implement a TinkerPop `TraversalStrategy` that optimizes `g.V().hasLabel()` to be "fast". So, i don't mean to say that it is a problem with OrientDB itself - it is a problem with the orientdb-gremlin. Does that make sense?

Comment: orientdb-gremlin already has a strategy - https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/blob/58e604b1b5f5d26e545f7a4beb9640b8a342d822/driver/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/orientdb/traversal/strategy/optimization/OrientGraphStepStrategy.java and it basically implants this step https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/blob/58e604b1b5f5d26e545f7a4beb9640b8a342d822/driver/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/orientdb/traversal/step/sideEffect/OrientGraphStep.java - Is `OrientGraphStep` doing the optimizations it should to get the performance in studio?